# sbt corrupts terminal display

Tags: macos, scala, terminal, sbt

This is a head scratcher for me; I'm on Mac OS 10.11.6 and I recently started using `sbt` for scala.  I'm running into the situation that every time I run an sbt command (e.g., `sbt run`, `sbt test`, etc.) for a specific small `Hello World` type project (included at the bottom of this post), I lose the ability to see my keyboard strokes afterwards.  My standard prompt is still there, but anything I type doesn't show up.  The keystrokes are still registered, in that I can type `ls`, hit ENTER and still see the output, but I can't see that I typed `ls`.

Perhaps even more perplexing is that if I run `sbt` and enter interactive mode, I *can* see my keystrokes!  Similarly, I can see my keystrokes in both the scala REPL and an IPython session.  However, I *can't* see my keystrokes in the standard `python` interpreter!

It doesn't appear to be an issue with my `$PS1`, as I can `unset PS1` and the issue is the same.  It also doesn't seem to occur for other projects.

The directory structure is the standard `sbt` structure, and this is in `src/main/scala/Hello.scala`:

```
object Hello extends App {                                                         
    val p = Person("Foo")                                              
    println("Hello from " + p.name)                                                
}                                                                                  

case class Person(var name: String)
```

Is it possible that when I copy / pasted this into `vim` (from a .pdf if that's relevant), some bizarre character got hidden in there?  Otherwise, what's going on with this?

Comment: It's possible but that should be easy to check by opening your file in any editor that can show invisible characters.

Comment: I am having the same issue here.

Comment: try to update OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Eric K Richardson at the sbt gitter channel:

> ```
> This is fixed now and should be in 1.0.2 - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/3507/commits/b6a3ca19373c2ffa17c5660fa74a9a4204948b6e
> You can type stty echo to restore window or use - https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras
> ```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Using `stty echo` is an easy immediate fix.

Comment: Also, if a future reader can't upgrade for whatever reason, sticking `ssbt() { sbt "$@"; stty echo }` in your `~/.bashrc` prevents you from having to type it every time.